# D3 rollup returning values based on dynamic array length

Tags: arrays, d3.js, rollup

I have a roll up function that I would want to return data based on a dynamic changing array of variables. In the code below, denominator is a variable, whose sum I'm able to return. In a different part of the code, I have an array of variables = [variable1,variable2,variable3] whose length is dependent on another function. It could have any number of variables. I would like a rollup to return the sum of variable1 ,variable2 and so on for each variable;

I know i can manually do it, like in the example below. But I'm certain there's a more logical way of getting a rollup to return values from an array of variables. I tried iterating through a for loop inside the return, but that didn't work.

```
            var districtDatabyDistrict = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) {
                    return +d.District_Code;
                })
                .rollup(function(d) {
                    return {
                        variable0: d3.sum(d, function(e) {
                            return e[variables[0]]; //Manually doing it.

                        denominator: d3.sum(d, function(e) {
                            return e[denominator];
                        }),
                        district_name: d[0].Area_Name,
                        state_name: d[0].State_Name,

                    }
                })
                .entries(file);
        }
```

Short version: How can I get the rollup to return sums of variable1,variable2,3 or as many variables that exist in the array?

Comment: what for-loop did you try?

Comment: Actually, I tried putting a for loop inside the return and tried to return a key, value kinda pair - and that wasn't smart.

Comment: How does one go about inserting a list of variable names, and their corresponding d3.sum formulas?

Comment: you already told this in the question, what for-loop did you try?

Comment: oops; here's what I tried. `for(count=0;count < array.length; count++){ return "variable"+count,array[count]}` - But that is silly.

Comment: `array[count]` is a variable name. Read a good book about JavaScript.

Comment: My bad, that's a typo. I did this `for(count=0;count < array.length; count++){ return "variable"+count,d3.sum(d, function(e) {
                            return e[array[count]];}` - that's supposed to get the sum of the  values in the column with the variable name.

Comment: now read a bit about JavaScript objects and fix the for loop